# DBContext SaveChanges method in UnitOfWork or in Repository? Which is better?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm trying to use Unit Of Work pattern for the first time in MVC application that already follows a Repository Pattern with Entity Framework DbContext.
My question is regarding the best place/practice on calling the Savechanges() method.

I see 2 approaches possible:

1. Call it in Unit Of Work class(Approach mentioned in [Asp.Net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application))
2. Call in Repository class

For the first approach, we have to call SaveChanges() on UnitOfWork instance injected in Controller. 
For the second approach, SaveChanges() will be encapsulated in Repository and all Controller needs to do is invoke method in Repository(provided by UnitOfWork) and SaveChanges() will be called inside Repository.

**Approach 1:**

```
 public class PostsController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IRepository<Post> _postRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public PostsController(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        if (uow == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uow));

        _uow = uow;
        _postRepository = uow.Repository<Post>();
        _categoryRepository = uow.Repository<Category>();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _postRepository.Add(post);
            _uow.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(post);
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private CodingSoldierDbContext _dbContext;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        _dbContext = dbContext as CodingSoldierDbContext;
    }
    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            return _repositories[typeof(T)] as IRepository<T>;
        }
        IRepository<T> repository = new Repository<T>(_dbContext);
        _repositories.Add(typeof(T), repository);
        return repository;
    }
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    CodingSoldierDbContext _dbContext;
    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        _dbContext = dbContext as CodingSoldierDbContext;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(item);
        //_dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**
Not adding code so that question remains short.
In Approach 1, in Create method in Controller, remove the line:

```
_uow.SaveChanges();
```

Remove "SaveChanges" method definition from UnitOfWork.

Uncomment commented line in Repository Class:

```
_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

I feel 2nd approach better than 1st approach in the sense code in controller is cleaner and SaveChanges is responsibility of the same class(Repository) who directly interact with DbContext.

Anyone, please let me know if you have any reason we should be following the 1st approach ?

Comment: tion evaluation requires all threads to run c# wpf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I prefer to implement the SaveChanges on the UnitOfWork context because if you edit several entities from several repositories, you don't want to execute the save changes on each repository.

Example:

```
var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create();
var categoryRepo = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Category>();
var postRepo= unitOfWork.GetRepository<Post>();

var cat = new Category("name");
categoryRepo.Add(cat);

var post = new Post("Title", "Message");
post.Category = cat;
postRepo.Add(post );

unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

It is easier to save the complete context (in one transition).

Comment: How about situations where you have to call `SaveChanges()` in the repository, for example when you need the id of an entity to insert something else inside the same function of the repository? You wouldn't have the id before saving the changes to the database.

Comment: I like this option, and for me I wouldn't pass the DbContext directly to the repository but an interface that removes the saveChanges, otherwise developers might be tempted to call it

Answer (score 1):

Both. In the UOW you need save changes to the context used by compound repositories. You need also savechanges method in the repositories like

```
public void SaveChanges() 
{
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

For repository that is used independently